# Iframe not loading fully within horizontal scrolling Div

Tags: html, css, iframe, widget, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to put a iframe within a horizontal scrolling div so that users can scroll across and see the Instagram posts. The issue that I am having with this is when the page loads it cuts off what ever is larger than the div. How do I load the whole iframe within the div without cutting any of the iframe content so that the users may scroll?

```css
#scroll {
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  margin:0px auto;
  background:#A3CBE0;
  overflow:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/bd/?h=anVpY2V8aW58MjAwfDEyfDJ8fHllc3w4fG5vbmV8b25TdGFydHxub3xubw==&ve=170515" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:2520px; height:670px"></iframe>
  <div style="height:1px;width:2520px; background-color:#A3CBE0;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres how the issue looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE33N.jpg

Comment: Your iframe seem to span across the whole width of your div fine, check here: http://output.jsbin.com/qenego . Is your issue related to any particular browser?

Comment: Its strange because it worked on your link, I'm thinking it could be because I am using wordpress on the site I'm trying to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a live link where i can inspect the code? If not, make sure you don't have any `overflow: hidden` rule on any of the parent elements of your iframe, including body and html elements.

Comment: You have a `max-width: 100%` on that iframe somewhere which messes your things up. Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc6xhlappx8i3ys/Screenshot%202015-05-22%2000.05.45.png?dl=0

Try removing it or, overriding by setting it to default which is `max-width: 0`

Comment: Thanks that's done it! Do you want to submit that as a answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: Sure, submitting as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `max-width: 100%` on that iframe somewhere which messes your things up.

Try removing it or, overriding by setting it to default which is `max-width: 0`

Comment: I removed the max-width: 100%; from the framework.css for anyone on WP who has the same issue later on

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JAVASCRIPT for that. Example:

```
yourIframeId.height = yourIframeId.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
```

That will set the height of your iframe accordingly with its content. Same proccess to change the div that wrapped it.